# az webapp deployment source config choose solution file

Tags: azure-cli

I am trying to deploy an app using the following:

```
az webapp deployment source config --branch master --manual-integration --name myapp --repo-url https://$GITUSERNAME:$GITUSERPASSWORD@dev.azure.com/<Company>/Project/_git/<repo> --resource-group my-windows-resources --repository-type git
```

The git repo contains 2 .sln solution files and this causes an error when attempting to deploy. Is there any way I can specify which solution file to use? I can seem to find a way in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest) but wondered if there might be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution where you create a .deployment file in the root of the solution with these contents

```
[config]
project = <PATHTOPROJECT>
command = deploy.cmd
```

Then a deploy.cmd

```
nuget.exe restore "<PATHTOSOLUTION>" -MSBuildPath "%MSBUILD_15_DIR%"
```

The `-MSBuildPath` may be optional for you